# Как вывести такой массив в php?

Tags: php, json

Как сделать массив, чтобы при выводе было такое?

```
{ 
   "Teams": { 
       "Units": [ 
           { "name":"RedDragon", "id":1, "attack":14, "protect":12, "speed":7, "ini":11, "curent":1, "team":1, "positionX":540, "positionY":190 }, 
           { "name":"Ghost", "id":5, "attack":5, "protect":3, "speed":4, "ini":10, "curent":0, "team":2, "positionX":1117, "positionY":71 } 
       ] 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Изучить синтаксис массивов в PHP

Comment: это же обычный json – https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

Начните с простого, дальше все поймете:

```
<?php

$data = array();
$data['teams'] = array();
$data['teams']['units'] = "blah blah";

echo json_encode($data);
```